# C# Microsoft Graph API - Filter Group Types Invalid filter clause

Tags: c#, graph

Iam trying to get all Groups from Azure AD without the O365 Groups (so only Security and Email Groups). Getting all Groups is no Problem. Iam trying to use a Filter but alwys get the "Invalid filter clause"

```
IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage groupsPage = await graphClient.Groups.Request(queryOptions)
            .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
            .Select("id,displayName,groupTypes")
            .Filter("groupTypes ne 'Unified'")
            .OrderBy("DisplayName")
            .GetAsync();
```

What am i doing wrong? or is there any other way to do this?

Thanks for your Time

Answer (score 0):

Sorry got it. Its not a Boolean so to Check for grouptype Use

```
NOT(groupTypes/any(s:s eq 'Unified'))
```